# Find files with same name but different extension

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, delete

I have a legacy application (unsupported) that generates PDF files of XLS, XLSX, DOC and DOCX on demand. The disk of that app is full and we need to delete those PDFs. So I'm searching for a script that allows me to locate all those PDFs and erase them later.

I've done some reasearch and this seams to do something similar, but I loose the complete folder route and also the file extension and size so I can manually look and check:

```
find . -exec bash -c 'basename "$0" ".${0##*.}"' {} \; | sort | uniq --repeated
```

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: Should an original file be in the same directory as the corresponding pdf file? Or could it be somewhere else in the directory tree.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -rC1 -- **/*.(#i)pdf(ND.e['()(($#)) $REPLY:r.(#i)(doc|xls)(x|)(N.Y1)'])
```

Would list the `pdf` regular files for which there's at least one doc/docx/xls/xlsx regular file with the same rootname (extensions matched case insensitively with `(#i)`).

Replace `print -rC1` (`print` `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn) with `rm` to remove them.